# grep with variable and string combined

Tags: regex, bash, variables, grep

I want to be able to use grep with variable and string combined for searching.

```
test="HTTP/[0-9].[0-9]" 
grep '$test [0-9][0-9][0-9] ||' some_file
```

Tried to put the variable in ${test} but that did not help.

How can i combine grep arguments with a variable and a string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to enclose your pattern in double quotes to enable variable expansion :

```
test="HTTP/[0-9].[0-9]" 
grep "$test [0-9][0-9][0-9] ||" some_file
```

---

```
test='expanded'
echo '$test' # will echo $test
echo "$test" # will echo expanded
```